# JSON iOS Dictionary Parse

Tags: ios, json

Looking at JSON for the first time using the Dribble API, in the app you enter and shot number and it returns the details of that shot. (Example URL http://api.dribbble.com/shots/1968486) I have got the App to return the JSON using the below code

```
self.JSONString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.dribbble.com/shots/%@", self.shotNumberTextField.text];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.JSONString]];

__block NSDictionary *json;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                           json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:nil];
                           NSLog(@"Async JSON: %@", json);
                       }];
```

This then exports the JSON to a Data Object, but how do I get the items such out of the JSON so I can show them in my app?

Many Thanks
James

Comment: `json[@"id"], json[@"title"]` and so on.

Comment: please can you expand further?

Answer (score 0):

You `NSDictionary` will be the JSON serialized, so it will have the same structure of the JSON (array, sub-objects, values, etc...). If you want to convert the `NSDictionary` into your `DataObject`, maybe you have to use a public library such as [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) or something else.